# How to respond with the correct challenge value when trying to enable event subscriptions for laravel-botman on slack

Tags: php, laravel, slack-api

*This is not a duplication of my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52850571/connecting-slack-to-botman-in-laravel-on-localhost).*

Am using [botman](https://botman.io/) to create a bot for my slack app.

Using the slack api, i have created a bot that i want to connect to botman on my laravel app. Am using ngrok to tunnel localhost. I have to get my url verified first in order to use it for the bot. Well i try to verify the url but i keep getting this error.

> Your request URL didn’t respond with the correct challenge value. Update your URL to receive a new request and value.

Checking the ngrok terminal shows that the request from slack is being received and the status is 200. If i reproduce the request using postman, the value of the challenge parameter is returned, on slack i still get the erorr. I use this code to load the slack driver on my routes file.

```
<?php
use BotMan\BotMan\BotMan;
use BotMan\BotMan\BotManFactory;
use BotMan\Drivers\Slack\SlackDriver;
use BotMan\BotMan\Drivers\DriverManager;

Route::match(['get', 'post'],'botman', function () {

    DriverManager::loadDriver(SlackDriver::class);

    // Create BotMan instance
    $config = [
            'slack' => [
                'token' => '***slack Token***' //slack token
                ]
            ];
    $botman = BotManFactory::create($config);

    // give the bot something to listen for.
    $botman->hears('hello', function (BotMan $bot) {
        $bot->reply('Hello yourself.');
    });

    // start listening
    $botman->listen();
});
```

I went a head to try force the response with the challenge parameter in the url like so on my routes file.

```
$payload = $request->json();

if ($payload->get('type') === 'url_verification') {
    return $payload->get('challenge');
}

SlackBot::hears('keyword', function (Bot $bot) {
    $bot->respond('lets begin');
});
```

This still does not work, i still get the `URL didn’t respond with the correct challenge value...` error.

What am i missing? or how should i use the slack driver to have it respond with the right parameters? The web driver works perfectly.

Comment: Its not clear from the code how exactly you are replying to the Slack challenge request. Maybe you can add that part of the code to your question? In general make sure that you respond with a JSON string containing all three properties: `token`, `challenge`, `type` as shown [here](https://api.slack.com/events-api#subscriptions).

Comment: from the bot man documenation, the first code snippet is what is avallable. the second code snippet is what i tried using to force the return of the challenge value. From my understanding  the slack driver has the second code snippet implemented somewhere

Comment: please add the name and a link to the library you are using so other people with the same issue can find it better.

Comment: @ErikKalkoken i added a link to the botman documentation https://botman.io/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed that the slack api expects the challenge value in json format.

simply doing  `return $payload->get('challenge');`  . does not do the trick.  I changed this to  `return response->json( return $payload->get('challenge'));`.  This got my url verified.

Am not sure whether this is an issue with the whole botman slack-driver , I didn't find anyone else with the same issue.